# Queue on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am pretty new to jQuery and I am having a bit of difficulty adapting to it being a Java nerd.

I am trying to make these 3 boxes so that when you click one of them, it comes forward and the two in the back dim and stay there, in the back. The problem is that, I want to make it so when you click more than 1 box consecutively, the second box clicked doesn't come forward until the animation ends, much like a queue of box clicks. Right now it's all mixed up and the dimming is fine but the boxes come forward as soon as I click them and not when they should.

I tried callbacks and deferred to no avail.

Here is the code:

Javascript:

```
var zindex = 1;

$('.box_listener').click(function() {

  $(this).css('z-index', zindex += 1);
  $(this).siblings('.box_listener').fadeTo(3000, 0.5);
  $(this).fadeTo(1, 1);
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/asger/5yvvgoda/14/

```js
var zindex = 1;

$('.box_listener').click(function() {

  $(this).css('z-index', zindex += 1);
  $(this).siblings('.box_listener').fadeTo(3000, 0.5);
  $(this).fadeTo(1, 1);
});
```

```css
#backgroundbox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #E5E8E8;
  z-index: -5;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.box_listener {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#redbox {
  left: 270px;
  top: 20px;
  border-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
}

#bluebox {
  left: 230px;
  top: 60px;
  border-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}

#greenbox {
  left: 210px;
  top: 77px;
  border-color: lightgreen;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="backgroundbox">

  <div class="box_listener" id="redbox">

  </div>

  <div class="box_listener" id="bluebox">

  </div>

  <div class="box_listener" id="greenbox">

  </div>

</div>
```

Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more bulletproof approach is to not use jQuery animations at all and instead use CSS transitions. The reason for this is twofold; CSS transitions can be automatically reversed and they can be GPU accelerated. It also means you don't have to artificially wait for the transition to complete before allowing user input.

To accomplish this, just set up two CSS classes; One that tells the elements you're going to animate how they should transition. The other class changes the values on the element, which causes the transition to happen. Then all jQuery needs to do is `addClass()` and `removeClass()` in order to cause the transitions to occur.

Below is an example of it in action. I've highlighted the most important aspects with comments.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  // remove the active class from all buttons,
  // this will reverse the transition
  $('.btn').removeClass('active');
  // apply it to only the current button clicked,
  //this will start the transition
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

  background: cornflowerblue;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  /* set up a transition on any css transformations like 
     translating, scaling, rotating, etc. */
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
}

/* when this class is added to the button it will scale it, but the 
   transition already on the button will make sure it happens slowly */
.active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Click the buttons</h2>

<button class="btn">First</button>
<button class="btn">Second</button>
<button class="btn">Third</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input on the subject. But seems like I forgot to mention I really have to use jQuery for the animations.

Comment: Interesting. Why do you have to?

Comment: Because it's part of the question... @Soviut

Comment: @AndréDaBaws Understanding why you need it a certain way helps us better answer your question.